# Does Heroku support Pubnub's python SDK v4

Tags: python, heroku

The examples from Heroku for working with the Python Pubnub SDK all [refer to version 3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pubnub#installing-the-python-sdk). This is scheduled for [end-of-life soon](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-twisted/pubnub-python-sdk-v3). Does Heroku support version 4?

Comment: the version 4 sdk should work as expected.

Comment: Quick answer - yes. Most, if not all, of the REST APIs in the PubNub v4 SDKs are the same as in v3. Use the [v3 to v4 migration guide for the PubNub SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/migration-guide-from-v3)